# Use UIKit Dynamics for insert/delete/move animations in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uicollectionview, uikit-dynamics

How can I replace the insert animation in a UICollectionView (called via **self.collectionView?.insertItemsAtIndexPaths**) with a UIKit Dynamics based movement, e.g. UISnapBehaviour? I am working with a subclassed **UICollectionViewFlowLayout**.

I understand that in general I can change e.g. the insert animation starting points by overriding the following method in my subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout

```
initialLayoutAttributesForAppearingItemAtIndexPath
```

… using different **UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes** but then the animation itself would still be a normal linear animation. So that doesn't seem to fit.

At which point (collectionView, cell or layout) would I add the UIDynamicsAnimator, define the initial position and then add the snap behaviour?

Comment: Did you solve your problem ?